# How to stop jquery mobile from truncating button text

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have text on a button that is being truncated, and I need it to be fully readable.  I've already tried

```
.ui-btn-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

and wrapping it in a div, but this didn't help.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Solution to this problem can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351891/jquery-mobile-button-text-auto-line-break

Answer (score 0):

`white-space` has nothing to do with overflow. You'll need to set either [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html) or [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow), depending on what the default stylesheet of jQuery Mobile is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-btn-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

works fine.

check where are you applying it? Is it being applied ? inspect the resulting html and check if it is not being overridden or something.