# jquery mobile button text auto line break

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want that the text in my button makes an automatic line break when it reaches the end of the button. When i us the normal jquery mobile style it truncates my text and places three dots like here:
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Qpe/1/)

i found a little workarround that these dots don't show up like here (white-space:normal didn't work for me)
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Qpe/2/)

has somone an idea how i can make it do auto line breaks ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't line break a single word in < CSS3 but there's a new css keyword in CSS3 called word-break that allows you to. This will obviously only work in CSS3 browsers.

Give your button a css class, if you want this to only apply to a single button, such as:

```
<a data-role="button" class='myButton'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
```

Then create a css style like this:

```
.myButton
{
   word-wrap: break-word !important;
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This will then wrap the word around into the specified width of the button.

Here's an updated [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Qpe/21/) to demonstrate.